# kotlin scope function as receiver without outer scope?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin scope functions like 'also', 'run', used in imbrication calls provide also the outer scope functions, for instance :

```kotlin
Instruction.builder().apply {
    setBefore(null) //ok, this function belongs to Instruction Object
    PrimitiveInstruction.builder().apply {
        setBefore(null) // NOPE ! this function doesn't belongs to PrimitiveInstruction
                        // but since it's called in a context of a preceding 'apply', it is available 
                        // it comes from outer scope...
    }
}
```

This behavior is really misleading...
Is there another way to manage that ? Or a way for kotlin to provide 'apply' function restricted to object's internal scope ?

thx

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The receiver of the second `setBefore` ***is*** `PrimitiveInstruction` for me, assuming `PrimitiveInstruction` has such a method and `builder` returns a `PrimitiveInstruction`.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by ‘[imbrication](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/imbrication)’? (I know a _lot_ of English words, but that one's new to me!) I'm guessing you mean ‘nested’, i.e. one call within another…?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `also` scope function instead. It allows a named parameter to avoid these kinds of ambiguities:

```
Instruction.builder().also { outerBuilder ->
    outerBuilder.setBefore(null)
    PrimitiveInstruction.builder().apply {
        outerBuilder.setBefore(null) // if that's what you want
        setBefore(null) // called on inner builder
    }
}
```

If you are building a DSL, you can use [`@DslMarker`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-safe-builders.html#scope-control-dslmarker) in your own custom scope functions to prevent them from seeing higher level objects' members.

But it cannot be logically extended to anything in a general scope function like `apply`. If `apply` could not see things that are in scope outside itself, you would hardly be able to do anything inside `apply` besides call member functions and pass them literals.